# WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/ does not work in Win7

Tags: python, apache

Using Apache 2.2 / Win7

In httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

....

WSGIScriptAlias /wsgi/ "J:/py.cherrypy/"

<Directory "J:/py.cherrypy">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
<Files "*.*">
</Files>
</Directory>
```

In J:/py.cherrypy/test.wsgi :

```
def application(environ, start_response):
 status = '200 OK' 
 output = 'Hello World!'

 response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
 start_response(status, response_headers)

 return [output]
```

Pointing to

```
http://localhost:8080/wsgi/test.wsgi
```

returns The requested URL /wsgi/test.wsgi was not found on this server.

localhost:8080 is fine

Comment: This is where we ask if httpd is bound to port 8080.

Comment: Yes, localhost:8080 is fine

Comment: Finally, I found a solution....

Answer (score 0):

With

```
  WSGIScriptAlias /myapp j:/py.cherrypy/test.wsgi
  <Directory j:/py.cherrypy>
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

wget 127.0.0.1:8080/myapp works fine